# How to disable formula error check in Excel programmatically

Tags: c#, excel, formula

I try to set formula to Excel cell in C# in several steps,  however during the process I set it, it seems Excel throws exception due to invalid formula.  I wonder how can I turn off the formula error check in C#. thanks

Edit 
The formula is too long, longer than 255 characters. 
So I can't set formula in one step. 
Have to set a short formula, then replace  see http://netoffice.codeplex.com/discussions/402947

see code below 
but I get an error in rng.Formula = onePart;

where Constants.CUT_LENGTH = 253, Constants.MAX_FORMULA_LENGTH = 255, Separator = "||"
I try to set EvaluateToError to false, still get an error

```
                XLApp.ErrorCheckingOptions.InconsistentFormula = false;
                XLApp.ErrorCheckingOptions.EvaluateToError = false;

                SetFormula(rangeFunction, formula);  


    public static void SetFormula(Range rng, string origFormula)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var onePart in CutStringIntoSubstrings(origFormula))
        {                
            if(i==0)
            {
                rng.Formula = onePart;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                rng.Replace(Constants.Separator, onePart);
            }
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<string> CutStringIntoSubstrings(string origFormula)
    {
        if (origFormula == null) yield return string.Empty;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(origFormula)) yield return string.Empty;
        if (origFormula.Length <= Constants.MAX_FORMULA_LENGTH) yield return origFormula;

        int startIdx = 0;
        int endIdx = startIdx + Constants.CUT_LENGTH;
        while(endIdx < origFormula.Length)
        {
            var substr = origFormula.Substring(startIdx, Constants.CUT_LENGTH);
            if(startIdx + Constants.CUT_LENGTH < origFormula.Length)
            {
                substr += Constants.Separator;
            }
            yield return substr;
            startIdx += Constants.CUT_LENGTH;
            endIdx = startIdx + Constants.CUT_LENGTH;
        }
        if (startIdx < origFormula.Length) yield return origFormula.Substring(startIdx);
    }
```

Comment: Why not built the formula first and then set it to the cell? Can you show some code?

Comment: Right, I see now. I assume you are using Excel 2003, since I can set very long formulae in Excel 2007 without problem. Perhaps your formula can be made smaller? Or failing that, is it possible to calculate part of it in one cell and then use the result in the rest of the formula in another cell?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.errorcheckingoptions_members.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.error.ignore(v=office.11).aspx

May b it might help :)